# extract url from facebook FQL

Tags: java, json, facebook-fql

I am stuck here and would like to extract using java the second link of the facebook query below

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "attachment": {
        "media": [
          {
            "photo": {
              "images": [
                {
                  "src": "https://fbcdn-photos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/1508634_699393523428883_996610253_s.png"
                },
                {
                  "src": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/s720x720/1508634_699393523428883_996610253_n.png"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

my code below, is obviously not working

```
try 
{
List<JsonObject> queryResults = facebookClient.executeFqlQuery(query, JsonObject.class);
if(!queryResults.isEmpty()) 
{
JsonObject facebookPosturl_J = queryResults.get(0);
facebook_post = facebookPosturl_J.getString("src");
}
}
catch (Exception e){logger.warn("Unexpected error", e);}
```

Comment: Please define "Not working".  What is it doing?  What is it supposed to do?

Comment: here is my error: 2013-12-23 08:44:37,730 WARN (Timer-0) [javafxapplication4.JavaFXApplication4] - Unexpected error
com.restfb.json.JsonException: JsonObject["src"] not found.

Comment: Can you show what is in "query" variable?

Comment: SELECT attachment.media.photo.images.src   FROM stream WHERE source_id = 187050104663230  AND type = 247 AND created_time > 1383293228 LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling:

```
facebookPosturl_J.getJsonArray("data").getJsonObject(0).getJsonObject("attachment").getJsonArray("media").getJsonObject(0).getJsonObject("photo").getJsonArray("images").getJsonObject(1).getString("src")
```

Comment: Thx, I get error [javafxapplication4.JavaFXApplication4] - Unexpected error
com.restfb.json.JsonException: JsonObject["data"] not found.

Comment: This is what I am using: facebook_Post_Url = queryResults.get(0).getJsonArray("data").getJsonObject(0).getJsonObject("attachment").getJsonArray("media").getJsonObject(0).getJsonObject("photo").getJsonArray("images").getJsonObject(1).getString("src");

Comment: JsonObject facebookPosturl_J = queryResults.get(0);
                                    facebook_Post_Url = queryResults.get(0).getJsonObject("attachment").getJsonArray("media").getJsonObject(0).getJsonObject("photo").getJsonArray("images").getJsonObject(1).getString("src");